# HR Migration: how do the keys change

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Short: how are the keys changed when migrating to HR.  Does just the App Name change or do the underlying id / names changed?

Long: I'm currently on M/S with a bunch of un-parented entities.  In switching to High Replication, I have to re-parent a number of entities (for eventual consistency).  I am parenting them without real keys (i.e. db.Key.from_path('ParentType', 'ParentId-CustomTag)).  I have a strong reason for doing this (to avoid having too many writes to a single entity group).

If the Keys and Parents are migrated in a way that preserves the underlying ID, then I don't have to re-re-parent on the HR side.  If they do change, then I need to re-re-parent on the HR side.

Comment: What's the connection between having 'fake' parents and overloading your entity groups?

Comment: I have an object, say a Request, that has many comments, payments, calls, etc tied to it.  Each of these groups individually won't be written to more than 1/s, but in aggregate definitely.  So if I parented them all with the Request object, the Request entity group would be overloaded on writes.  But if I parent each separately with Request-Call, Request-Comment, etc, then I won't violate the 1/s.

Comment: Why parent them at all? The only reason you should be using entity groups is if you need to do transactions across entities in a group.

Comment: Eventual consistency is not OK for a lot of the views.  For example, when a claim is made on a Request, I need to show an aggregate view of all the claims.  A gql query could fail with eventual consistency.  I'm not wrong that the classic example of using entity groups is a blogger seeing his comment show up, right?  There's nothing 'transactional' about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying ids remain the same after migration. Only the app field of the key changes.